# Neither he can eat nor sleep

Tags: conjunctions, correlating-conjunctions

it may not be a valid question but I wanna know that 'is the above mentioned sentence correct or incorrect'? 
Because as I was discussing this sentence with one of my friends, he told me that you haven't used 'neither...nor' in a correct way!
I got astonished at that time but then he told me that 'Neither can he eat nor sleep' is grammatically correct. But now I want your views about my friend's sentence and mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idiomatic choices are:

> He can't either eat or sleep.
>
> He can neither eat nor sleep.
>
> Neither can he eat nor sleep. <sup>note the inversion</sup>

The last is something of an archaism, and would be considered formal or literary and is rarely used.